# How to take the log of an equation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am researching a software reliability model that has many parameters that need to be estimated. I want to use a maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) to estimate those parameters, but my model is too complicated to derive the log-likelihood function (namely LL in the following picture) from the likelihood function (namely L in the following picture).

When I try to execute `Log[L]` in *Mathematica*, I don't get the expected answer (LL). So my question is, how can I get expected answer after taking the log of the equation? Or can *Mathematica* not do this operation?

Link of code:https://www.dropbox.com/s/e81ndt3kgdq5dsw/GO_model.nb

[image]

Comment: Please look up `Simplify`, `FullSimplify` and `ComplexityFunction`. Also search this site for useful posts on those.

Comment: Can you add the exact code instead the pictures of it ?

Comment: Sorry, I am rookie in here, so I directly post the link for code in the picture.

Comment: I try to input `SuperLog[On]`,but I just get output `SuperLog[On]`.

Comment: @user2336074 Unfortunately the `SuperLog` thing referenced in the top answer is only available by purchasing the add-on package **mathStatica**.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard♦ I find the paper http://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/1530/1/paper_141.pdf, and it said "This package is also available electronically by anonymous ftp at 
ftp://ftp.tri.org.au/SMLE.m". But,I still can't download the package from ftp://ftp.tri.org.au/SMLE.m.

Comment: Just use the replacement rule in the question, it works fine for your expression.

Comment: @ssch Sorry I don't understand what replacement rule means. And can I use SuperLog for free? Thanks for your help.